# ansible loop over list

Tags: ansible, splunk

I have an inventory (this can be changed):

```
index:
  - indexName: "AAA"
    homePath: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/db"
    coldPath: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/colddb"
    thawedPath: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/thaweddb"
    repFactor: "auto"
  - indexName: "BBB"
    homePath: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/db"
    coldPath: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/colddb"
    thawedPath: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/thaweddb"
    repFactor: "auto"
```

I want to loop over the indexes, but also want to use key value. like this:

```
- name: Write paths for the index
  ini_file:
    dest: "{{ splunk.home }}/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf"
    section: "{{ index.indexName }}"
    option: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
    - { key: "homePath", value: "{{ index.homePath | default('', true) }}" }
    - { key: "thawedPath", value: "{{ index.thawedPath | default('', true) }}" }
    - { key: "coldPath", value: "{{ index.coldPath | default('', true) }}" }
    - { key: "repFactor", value: "{{ index.repFactor | default('', true) }}" }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Use [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html#subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries). Prepare the structure of the data first. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        index2: "{{ index2|default([]) +
                    [{'indexName': item.indexName, 'conf': conf}] }}"
      loop: "{{ index }}"
      vars:
        conf: "{{ item|dict2items|
                  rejectattr('key', '==', 'indexName')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: index2
```

give

```yaml
  index2:
  - conf:
    - key: homePath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/db
    - key: coldPath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/colddb
    - key: thawedPath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/thaweddb
    - key: repFactor
      value: auto
    indexName: AAA
  - conf:
    - key: homePath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/db
    - key: coldPath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/colddb
    - key: thawedPath
      value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/thaweddb
    - key: repFactor
      value: auto
    indexName: BBB
```

Then use the list `index2` and review the items

```yaml
    - name: Write paths for the index
      # ini_file:
      debug:
        msg:
          - "dest: {{ splunk.home }}/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf"
          - "section: {{ item.0.indexName }}"
          - "option: {{ item.1.key }}"
          - "value: {{ item.1.value }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', index2, 'conf') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: AAA'
  - 'option: homePath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/db'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: AAA'
  - 'option: coldPath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/colddb'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: AAA'
  - 'option: thawedPath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/thaweddb'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: AAA'
  - 'option: repFactor'
  - 'value: auto'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: BBB'
  - 'option: homePath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/db'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: BBB'
  - 'option: coldPath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/colddb'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: BBB'
  - 'option: thawedPath'
  - 'value: $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/thaweddb'

  msg:
  - 'dest: splunk_home/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf'
  - 'section: BBB'
  - 'option: repFactor'
  - 'value: auto
```

If this is what you want write the file. For example

```yaml
    - name: Write paths for the index
      ini_file:
        dest: indexes.conf
        section: "{{ item.0.indexName }}"
        option: "{{ item.1.key }}"
        value: "{{ item.1.value }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', index2, 'conf') }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat indexes.conf 

[AAA]
homePath = $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/db
coldPath = $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/colddb
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/AAA/thaweddb
repFactor = auto
[BBB]
homePath = $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/db
coldPath = $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/colddb
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/BBB/thaweddb
repFactor = auto
```

Answer (score 0):

With the actual data structure, you could reach your goal with something like the following. We have the `index` list on one side and a list of keys we want to reference on the other. The [`product` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-nested-lists) creates a global list we can loop other to get each possible mix from the two lists:

```yaml
- name: Write paths for the index
  ini_file:
    dest: "{{ splunk.home }}/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf"
    section: "{{ item.0.indexName }}"
    option: "{{ item.1 }}"
    value: "{{ item.0[item.1] | default('', true) }}"
  with_items: {{ index | product(['homePath', 'coldPath', 'thawedPath', 'repFactor']) | list }}
```

Meanwhile, this still requires you to hardcode the list of keys you need to loop over. Moreover, this will be hard to maintain if you need to add certain keys to indexes that are not available for others.

Since you mentioned you could eventually modify your data, I would suggest the following structure which will be easier to go through in one go with the [`subelements` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements). This is an idea, you can modify to suit your exact needs.

```yaml
index:
  - indexName: "AAA"
    options:
      - name: homePath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/db"
      - name: coldPath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/colddb"
      - name: thawedPath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/AAA/thaweddb"
      - name: repFactor
        value: "auto"
  - indexName: "BBB"
    options:
      - name: homePath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/db"
      - name: coldPath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/colddb"
      - name: thawedPath
        value: "$SPLUNK_DB/BBB/thaweddb"
      - name: repFactor
        value: "auto"
```

And you task would then look like:

```yaml
- name: Write paths for the index
  ini_file:
    dest: "{{ splunk.home }}/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf"
    section: "{{ item.0.indexName }}"
    option: "{{ item.1.name }}"
    value: "{{ item.1.value }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', index, 'options') }}"
```